# Do you get multiplayer on NFS: Most Wanted app?

Tags: ios, android, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

I'm in the app version, and was wondering how I can play online with my friend (who also has the app version). Does anyone know? If so, can you tell me how? With detailed steps please!

Comment: What platform? Android? iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 2):

In Need for Speed Most Wanted on Android, you can use the "Speed Wall" to compete against your friends; best racing times, however there is no "multiplayer" functionality in this game in the traditional sense so you cannot race against your friends directly.

Answer (score 1):

The app version does not have a multiplayer function. 
It might be added in the future.